# QGIS create contour from DEM

Tags: qgis, dem, contour

I have created a DEM from points using the raster interpolation method, the TIN function, based on elevation of each point.  However, when I try to create a contourline, the results show the contours following the lines/boundaries of the 5m cells I've created using the dem. Am I specifying the right values for cell size, search radius, grid size etc with the interpolation?

Ultimately I want to insert the raster I have created into a DEM based on 2m lidar data, where the dem created using the interpolated grid is to replace for missing values/no data coverage in the lidar data.

Comment: Can you describe more clearly what you did and what you want to achieve? In addition, what version of QGIS are you using?

Comment: Welcome to Geographic Information Systems! Welcome to GIS SE! We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site. Your questions should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that. Please check out our short [tour] for more about how the site works.

Comment: How are you creating the contours, are you just using the native Contour algorithm?

Comment: Hi I am using QGIS 2.18 with interpolation plug in added.  What I want to do is to fill in a gap in 2m Lidar DTM, with an idea I had of creating points and then obtaining height data for each point.  Then create a raster of the points using the interpolation plug in, with the field to be interpolated being the height data.  I then want to merge the dem created from the points with the lidar data to create a seamless raster,  When I do this using the merge raster command, the cell boundaries of the interpolated grid seem to show over the lidar data.  For contours,I am using the raster function.